# Issue of prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a simple issue, but i can't understand.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var man = function(){

    var age = 1;

    this.shoes = 2;

};

man.prototype = {

    create: function(){

        //age = 5;
        console.log(age);
        console.log(this.shoes);

    }

}
var man1 = new man;
man1.create();
</script>
```

-Ok,I create a man with 2 vars, age and shoes. I use "this" only in shoes. After I prototype a method in man.

-If I execute this code, first console.log say me:

Uncaught ReferenceError: age is not defined (logic)

And the second console is "2" (correct).

-If I write: console.log(this.age) the message error is: undefined.

-But if I put a value for age (age=5)(without using "var" for create var) in new method, it works.

Why I can only use age var if I put a value before read this but?

Comment: Scope issue. It can not be accessed by your prototype function. Moving it outside of your constructor makes it accessible however. Defining `age=5` in the prototype actually does not change your first `age` variable because that one is protected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The age variable is within the "constructors" closure, which makes it only available there. You can use the age variable inside that function (closure), but not outside.

If you want to make it accessable from outside, add it to this or make a getter function like:

```
var man = function(){
    var age = 1;
    this.shoes = 2;
    this.getAge = function() { return age; };
};
```

But if you don't put declare the variable inside the function, but still set it, then it will be defined on the global object, in the browser `window`. This will not make age available on the man object, but you will get access to it anywhere. Here's an to clarify a bit:

```
function tellAgeDelayedGlobal() {
    age = 1;
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(age) }, 1000);   
}

function tellAgeDelayedDeclared() {
    var age = 1;
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(age) }, 1000);   
}

tellAgeDelayedGlobal();
tellAgeDelayedDeclared();
age = 2;
```

this will print to console:

```
2
1
```

Comment: oh, just read the description again and see now that I dont answer the question. Will fix

Comment: Ok, I understand, the problem is that I thought all the time that the variables only could initiate with "var" term, not without.  ;)

Comment: Extended my answer with an explanation on the why not declaring the variable in the function makes it available everywhere.

Comment: Why the people use the "var" term to initiate variables, if this is not necessary? (like php)

Comment: Oh then I think you misunderstood it. If you don't declare the variable by addng the `var`, then it will be declared on the global object. Meaning setting it will change it every time. I'll try to extend my explanation.

Comment: @Phyron Without `var` it automatically is global -> belongs to the window object

Comment: @EmilIngerslev Whoops, my comment was meant for Phyron

Comment: Does this extension to my answer help?

Comment: @EmilIngerslev I think it is a very good explanation of the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `var` inside a function it is available within it(local scope).

```
var man = function(){

    var age = 1;

    this.shoes = 2;

};
```

Here `age` will be available only in the `man` method / constructor because this creates a local scope or rather is `private` to the constructor.

```
man.prototype = {

    create: function(){

        age = 5;
        console.log(age);
        console.log(this.shoes);

    }

}
```

Here `age` will create a global scope. That is, this is equivalent to `window.age = 5` and hence making it available in the entire app. Because of which you will be able to retrieve the value in any function since it is global now.

This must be avoided since it will not be automatically garbage collected(GC). If you really need it because other parts of your code has a dependency w.r.t. it, you can namespace it like: `MyApp.age = 5`. But w.r.t your current situation, I do not find a need in here.